# Spring Boot mix session data

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, jsp

I have a project based on Spring Boot and Java, with a WebController and jsp files which connect to that controller for the exchange of data.
I implemented the HTTPSession value on that Controller, and a Java Class named "Login" in order to manage multiple users in the Application which is deployed in a server with Tomcat 9.

The purpose of the application is to make an energetic study, and the problem is that when 2 different users connect, the data of both sessions get mixed and at the end, both users end working on the same study and with the same data.

The app technology is the following: In a Spring Controller I have the Services which connect to a SQL Database, and in the Web the jsp files are forms in HTML to send the data to the controller.

I tried by changing the configuration of the Tomcat adding memory but that wasn't the solution, neither is Database problem because the ids and the data store correctly.

I tried by making synchronized the methods of the Java controller, and with the "@EnableASync" annotation

There´s only one Controller for the jsp views, which has global variables the services to connect to SQL and a ViewModel in order to get it at the jsp views

```
//Here, I get the user who do the login and store it in the HttpSession
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public synchronized String loginPost(HttpSession session, @RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("login") String passwd) {
        Login login = loginService.buscarPorUsuario(email);
        session.setAttribute("usuario", login);
}

//A sample method in the controller, calls a jsp named "NuevoAutoconsumo"
@RequestMapping(value = "/Solar/NuevoAutoconsumo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public synchronized String NuevoEstudioSolAutoconsumo(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        return "/Solar/NuevoAutoconsumo";
    }


//In the controller, I have the following variables created:
//services for the Database
private final ConsumosManualesService consumosManualesService;
private final OfertaGeneradaService ofertasGeneradasService;
private final MaterialPresupuestoService materialesPresupuestoService;
//Global variable to store the data which is sent to the jsp views
private final EstudioSolarViewModel estudioViewModel;
```

I expected that as I save the user in the session, the program works separately depending on the session.get("user") but the data gets mixed.

I think that the big error here is that the data get mixed when the jsp file send the data to the Java Controller, but I don´t know for sure and I don´t get any error messages at the console.

Comment: If you require users to log in to your webapp, why aren't you using Spring Security to manage that?

Comment: As I understand , you are using Spring to build the app.  That means the application will come with Spring provided infrastructure with it, like DispatcherServlet . So , it is better to use spring provided mechanism to do session management in this case . If you were not using spring , you had the option of programmatically managing the session like this : https://medium.com/@kasunpdh/session-management-in-java-using-servlet-filters-and-cookies-7c536b40448f#targetText=In%20session%20management%2C%20Tomcat%20creates,sends%20along%20with%20the%20response.

Comment: Yes I'm using Spring to buid the app, so, should I try with Spring Security? Or with that "DispacherServlet"? Thanks for your answers @Atul

Comment: @Andreas I will check that Spring Security, do you know a page with good documentation? Thanks!